# Django: serialize an annotated and aggregated queryset to GeoJSON

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm, geodjango

I am trying to use Django ORM (or any other way using Django) to execute this query (PostgreSQL) AND send the result back to the front end in GeoJSON format.
I am using Django 2.2.15

```
SELECT string_agg(name, '; '), geom
FROM appname_gis_observation
where sp_order = 'order1'
GROUP BY geom;
```

The model looks like this (models.py)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class gis_observation(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    sp_order = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    geom = models.MultiPointField(srid=4326)
```

So I thought this would work (views.py)

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from .models import *
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates.general import StringAgg

def show_observation(request):
  results = gis_observation.objects.values('geom').filter(sp_order='order1').annotate(newname=StringAgg('name', delimiter='; '))      
  data_geojson = serialize('geojson', results, geometry_field='geom', fields=('newname',))  
  return render(request, "visualize.html", {"obs" : data_geojson})
```

The ORM query works fine in the Django shell but Django complains at the ***serialize*** step: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'`.

Even if the ***serialize*** step worked, I suspect it would skip my annotated field (by reading other posts)

Apparently I am not the only one who met that same problem but I could not find a solution for it.

Comment: `ValuesQueryset` is a ***`list`*** like object, not a *`dict`* like object

Comment: I just edited the answer and removed the reference to ValuesQueryset. I just noticed that it is actually a Queryset object. But what does the  ```AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'  ``` mean and how can I serialize my queryset into a GeoJSON?

Comment: from where that `serialize` comes? Could you create a ***minimal reproducible example*** ?

Comment: Sure. I just edited the question and added some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with. Frankly I'd be glad to accept another answer, so any proposal still welcome!
In the end, I built a Geojson array by looping though the result set. I guess I could as well have gone for a cursor sql query instead and skip the orm api entirely.

```
        queryset = gis_species_observation.objects.values('geom').filter(sp_order='order1').annotate(name=StringAgg('name', delimiter='; '))
        mydict = []
        results = list(queryset)
        for result in results: 
            rec = {}
            rec["type"] = "Feature"
            rec["geometry"] = json.loads(result["geom"].geojson)            
            rec["properties"] = {"name":result["name"]}
            mydict.append(rec)
        data_geojson = json.dumps(mydict)
        return render(request, "visualize_romania.html", {"mynames" :data_geojson})
```